# Mixing declarative beans and annotated beans: org.hibernate.HibernateException No Session found for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, transactional, transactionmanager

I get "No Session found for current thread".
I suppose the problem is in mixing declarative xml beans and annotated beans.
Following, I'll resume my config.

### MyLibrary Project

Spring 3.1.4
Hibernate 4

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

<context:component-scan 
    base-package="com.mycompany.dao.core, com.mycompany.services.core,
                  com.mycompany.permissionEvaluator" />

<import resource="model-core-security.xml" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
... (sessionFactory ecc...)
```

**model-core-security.xml**

```
<bean id="expressionHandler"
class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
</bean>

<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>
```

With component-scan I create beans: AccountService, AccountDAO and PermissionEvaluator.

**AccountService.java (com.mycompany.services)**

```
@Service("accountService")
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Resource
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;

   ...
}
```

**AccountDAO.java (com.mycompany.dao)**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HibernateAccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {

   ...query...
}
```

(AccountService e AccountDAO are transactional)

Now, within **AccountController.java** I call *accountService.listAccounts()* and **it's all right**!

But, if I inject AccountService into PermissionEvaluator class (following snippet), AccountController gets **No Session found for current thread** when invokes *accountService.listAccounts()*

**PermissionEvaluator.java (com.mycompany.permissionEvaluator)**

```
Component("permissionEvaluator")
public class PermissionEvaluatorImpl implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Resource
    private AccountService accountService;

    ...
}
```

I use PermissionEvaluator (with AccountService, AccountDAO) created by component-scan in expressionHandler bean declared in model-core-security.xml.

Might it be the cause of "no session found for currend thread"?

Answer (score -1):

@Transactional
what's ur import package

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; ??

U can try to import "import javax.transaction.Transactional;"