# @transactional and <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>. Still getting-no-session-found-for-current-thread-exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I was trying this example from beingjavaguys . I made some changes. Removed some of XML config and added annotations for entities.

The example has sessionFactory.opensession() for each method. I went with getCurrentSession() and I am getting this error.

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

I have found this threads to get the problem sorted.

[Spring and hibernate: No Session found for current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298483/spring-and-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread)

[Getting "No Session found for current thread" exception when using getCurrentSession()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937477/getting-no-session-found-for-current-thread-exception-when-using-getcurrentses)

[Spring-Hibernate - No Session found for current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716939/spring-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread)

[Mixing declarative beans and annotated beans: org.hibernate.HibernateException No Session found for current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751049/mixing-declarative-beans-and-annotated-beans-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-n)

So, I put  in my orm-context.xml ( tried with proxy-target-class="true" once and then removing it also) . 
Used @transactional (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional) in service and DAO . Here I tried all combo .. just putting @transactional in service or in DAO and both!
but still the error persisted.

I am using standard structure with service interface,dao interface. I have autowired service to controller, DAO to service.

Here is my orm-context.xml

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <property name="annotatedClasses">  
        <list>  
            <value>com.beingjavaguys.domain.Employee</value>  
        </list>  
    </property>  -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.beingjavaguys.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

So, I thought perhaps adding annotated classes list will help instead of scanning entire domain package. Didn't Help.

Here is my Spring-context.xml

```
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.beingjavaguys" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Searching some other threads got me to include even cg-lib. But that didn't solve the error.

I am using Spring 4.0.5 and Hibernate 4.3.5 FINAL.

Can anybody please suggest something that I can try.

---Update-----

Using Web.xml to load orm-context and Spring-context.

Here is my Web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/root-context.xml
    /WEB-INF/orm-context.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

DataServiceImpl:

```
 @Autowired
 DataDao dataDao;

 @Override
 @Transactional
public List<Employee> getList() {
    return dataDao.getList();
}
```

DataDaoImpl

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<Employee> getList() {
    try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria("Employee").list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Adding StackTrace:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.beingjavaguys.dao.DataDaoImpl.getList(DataDaoImpl.java:23)
    at com.beingjavaguys.services.DataServiceImpl.getList(DataServiceImpl.java:22)
    at com.beingjavaguys.controller.DataController.getList(DataController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Show your code. Show the complete stack trace of the exception. Tell us how these two xml files are used.

Comment: I have added Code above as Update. The impls are implementing interfaces. Added Stack Trace.

Comment: You're scanning all your classes, instead of just the web-releted classes, in the child mvc context. The beans used are thus instantiated by the child context instead of the root context where the TransactionManager is defined. I personally prefer using a single context. That makes things simpler.

Comment: So is <context:component-scan base-package="com.beingjavaguys" />
 the problem. Should I specifically mention the controller and service and Dao instead ,so Domain class is not scanned

Comment: Or should Include one more subpackage and include all COntroller,services and all in it. Perhaps then use the subpackage as base package for scanning.

Comment: The child web context should normally only include web-related stuff: MVC controllers, advices, etc. The transactional services and DAOs should be part of the root context where the transaction manager is defined. Or you could not have any root context, and define everything in the web context.

Comment: Sorry; I didn't understand what you mean by web-related classes. Aren't all classes web-related ?

Comment: No. Services and DAOs are not web-related. MVC controllers are specifically designed to respond to HTTP requests. Services and DAOs are just software components that can be used in any context.

Comment: But Scanning only controllers would give me autowiring error for ServiceImple and then for DAOImpl . Also, I had read somewhere that Transaction Manager should be defined in root Context... bit confused here..

Comment: No, because the DAOs and services should be scanned by the root context. root context: scan everything except web-specific stuff. web context: scan nothing except web-specific stuff.

Comment: I still had to Scan everything using base-package="com.beingjavaguys" .because using only controller gave me autowiring error. Bit as you said .. I moved everything from orm-context to Spring-context.  That removed the error. Big Thanks

Comment: Though If i have to seperate the different config files and load it ..how would I do it ? Just for clarity sake .. evrything in servlet-context loads in webapplicationcontext and everything in Root-context loads in ApplicationContext ?

Comment: Just as I said: scan the web-related stuff in the web context, and scan everything else in the root context.